# Usar layout android aleatoriamente

Tags: android, android-layout

Boas pessoal, pretendo "chamar" um layout aleatoriamente, o problema está em chamá-lo, pensei em guardar todos os layouts num array e com base nos números gerados aleatoriamente chamar o layout nessa posição do array, pensei fazer desta forma:

```
    String listalayouts[] = new String[100];
    listalayouts[0]="layout1.xml";

    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String x="R.layout."+listalayouts[0];
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(x);
        }
    });
```

Isto não funciona pois x não é do tipo View e não dá para fazer cast de String para view.
Alguém tem uma solução?

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Alternar entre *layouts* com `setContentView()` não é uma boa ideia, irá trazer muitos problemas. Note que o método `findViewById()` está directamente ligado com o *layout* indicado com `setContentView()`. Sugiro que use *Fragments*.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa passar uma `View` pro método `setContentView()`. Esse método também aceita um `int` como parâmetro, sendo que este `int` é o **id** do layout que você quer usar.

Portanto, o que você pode fazer, é achar o **id** correspondente ao layout que você quer usar e passá-lo como parâmetro no método `setContentView()`. No seu caso, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
String listalayouts[] = new String[100];

listalayouts[0]="layout1"; // Não é necessário colocar a extensão ".xml"

botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 // Pega o id do layout baseado no nome dele
 // o parametro "layout" no getIdentifier() deve ser mantido

 int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(listalayouts[0],"layout", context.getPackageName());

    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(resId);
    }
});
```